# Creating python module with command line arguments

Tags: python, pip

I've uploaded a python module to pypi and locally installed the module with:

pip install microarray_quantilenorm

I'm trying to run the module on commandline with pass-through arguments.

When I call the python script directly from site-packages, everything works fine.

```
python /site-packages/microarray_quantilenorm/microarray_quantilenorm.py *csv
```

But calling:

```
python -m microarray_quantilenorm.__main__ *csv
```

OR:

```
python -m microarray_quantilenorm *csv
```

Results in:

```
/anaconda/bin/python: No module named microarray_quantilenorm.__main__
```

I cannot track down to whether there is an issue in setup.py, my __init__.py or elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of `__main__.py` is that it's the file that's run when the package is run as a module. In other words, just do `python -m microarray_quantilenorm`, not `python -m microarray_quantilenorm.__main__`.

However, usually, there's an even better solution. Assuming you're using `setuptools` rather than trying to do the whole mess manually, use a [`console_scripts` entry point](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#scripts). This will make the setup process automatically create a script named `microarray_quantilenorm` and install it in your `bin` or `scripts` directory that does the right thing to load the package and run its main code (or, if you prefer, some other code within it).

Comment: Question on the syntax of console_scripts, what syntax would I use to call the script? using microarray_quantilenorm=microarray_quantilenorm:main results in error.

Comment: @user2277435: See [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation). But first, did you remember the quotes? Second, `main` is the name of a _function_ to call. Does your `microarray_quantilenorm.__main__` have a `main` function? If this isn't enough to help, I'd suggest creating a new question, where you can include details like what error it results in and exactly what you put where.

Comment: Yes, could not see which syntax to use based on docs, but it is called in setup.py with quotes. Yes, my python script contains a main function. I'll post as a separate question if I can't resolve after more time. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2277435: The docs I linked in the answer just give a minimal example, but the docs I linked in the comment (which should also be linked somewhere from the other docs, I hope) have a little more information.